how can i get rid of the bug when if you press shift quickly after stamina runs out you keep running?
i've got an annoying bug i cant in my script for roblox, if you quickly press shift after stamina reached 0 you'll keep running while stamina recharges
if you notice any other bugs please tell me
its probably because of gradual sped change i added, but i need it
handler script:
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local StaminaGui = script.Parent
local Holder = StaminaGui:WaitForChild("Holder")
local Bar = Holder:WaitForChild("Bar")
local AmtDisplay = Holder:WaitForChild("AmtDisplay")
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Stamina = script.Stamina

local isRunning = false
local gotTired = false
local maxWalkSpeed = 35 -- Max speed when sprinting
local normalWalkSpeed = 20 -- Default speed
local transitioningSpeed = false

-- Function to smoothly change the walk speed
local function changeWalkSpeed(targetSpeed, duration)
    if transitioningSpeed then
        return
    end
    transitioningSpeed = true
    local startTime = tick()
    local initialSpeed = humanoid.WalkSpeed
    while humanoid.WalkSpeed ~= targetSpeed do
        local elapsedTime = tick() - startTime
        local t = math.clamp(elapsedTime / duration, 0, 1)
        humanoid.WalkSpeed = initialSpeed + (targetSpeed - initialSpeed) * t
        wait()
    end
    transitioningSpeed = false
end

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        if humanoid.MoveDirection.magnitude > 0 then -- Check if the player is already moving
            if Stamina.Value >= 1 then
                if gotTired == false then
                    isRunning = true
                    script.InSprint.Enabled = true
                    script.OutSprint.Enabled = false
                    changeWalkSpeed(maxWalkSpeed, 1.5) -- Smoothly transition to sprint speed over 1.5 seconds
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)

UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        isRunning = false
        script.InSprint.Enabled = false
        script.OutSprint.Enabled = true
        changeWalkSpeed(normalWalkSpeed, 1.5) -- Smoothly transition back to default speed over 1.5 seconds
    end
end)

script.Tired.Event:Connect(function()
    if Stamina.Value <= 0 then
        humanoid.WalkSpeed = normalWalkSpeed
        script.InSprint.Enabled = false
        script.OutSprint.Enabled = true
        gotTired = true
        wait(1)
        gotTired = false
    end
end)

while true do
    wait()
    AmtDisplay.Text = "STAMINA: " .. Stamina.Value .. "/100"
    game:GetService("TweenService"):Create(Bar, TweenInfo.new(0.075, Enum.EasingStyle.Quint), {Size = UDim2.new(Stamina.Value / 100, 0, 1, 0)}):Play()
end

in sprint:
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

local Stamina = script.Parent.Stamina

while true do
    wait()
    
    if Stamina.Value <= 0 then
        
    else
        
        repeat
            wait(0.08)
            Stamina.Value = Stamina.Value - 1
        until Stamina.Value <= 0
        
        script.Parent.Tired:Fire()
        
        break
    end
end


out sprint:
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

local Stamina = script.Parent.Stamina

while true do
    wait()
    
    
    if Stamina.Value >= 100 then
        
    else
        
        repeat
            wait(0.11)
            Stamina.Value = Stamina.Value + 1
        until Stamina.Value >= 100
    end
end

how it looks in explorer
tried rewriting a code a few times, did nothing
if i changed holding sprint to just pressing it didnt get any better too, i mean there was some improvements but its not what i need
